# How to avoid Jenkins agent downloading dependencies on every build?

Tags: maven, jenkins

In my company, I can use a devops platform where I can run my maven build on an agent.

This agent is created for each build, and it has its own local **empty** repositories. When the build occurs, the dependencies are downloaded every time from the company mirrors which takes time and obfuscates the build logs.

What would be the way to avoid this ?

P.S. : There is a strong constraint which is projects shouldn't be able to call an "install" of their project in the common/shared local repository which would be a security flaw, but should be able to write their new dependencies if needed.

Comment: Usually, my best idea about this is pooling a number of local repositories. But if you want to avoid any way to install to the local repository, I guess you cannot do that.

Comment: First depending on your [Maven version 3.6.1+](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.6.1/release-notes.html) you can use `--no-transfer-progress` to prevent cluttering the build output with Download messages. This does of course not prevent the downloading of the artifacts which makes sure each build is clean. If projects are needed by other projects they need to do a `mvn deploy` via a repo manager ... A common shared local repository should not being done. Each build should be separated. The question if you need the `mvn install` or would be a `mvn deploy` better ?

Comment: Hi Mr Marbaise, thanks for the maven option "--no-transfer-progress" this will be useful ! About the rest of your comment, I don't understand what you mean or suggest. The need would be to have to get public dependencies from a locally accessible repository instead of downloading them, for interdependant projects, they just "deploy" their artifacts in a common nexus, these ones will be downloaded no matter what. To be more clear : the common shared local repository would be only for public dependencies found in mirrors of public repositories.